# ActiveAdmin asset issues in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, gemfile

I've been trying to get ActiveAdmin to work with my Rails 3.1.1 application. It mostly works until I was looking at the web developers console and noticed images weren't being loaded:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/images/active_admin/datepicker/datepicker-nipple.png 404 (Not Found)
```

I came across some people with similar problems, pointing out the url should have been generated with 'assets' not images. I tried the recommendations I found to update the 'sass-rails' gem but I had no luck.

I tried to start a brand new application from scratch with Rails 3.1.1 (the original app was Rails 3.1.0 not sure if the upgrade made the difference then a fresh start) and did the recommended fixes first and now every image loads fine. I tried to copy the similar part of the Gemfile back but it didn't seem to fix my actually application's problem. This is the area around the related lines in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.4'
gem 'meta_search',    '>= 1.1.0.pre'
gem 'activeadmin'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed this by completely uninstalling gems and deleting the gemset I was using with RVM for this project and redoing everything in a new version of rails (2.3). Following a similar issue on github leads me to believe this isn't an issue in a new release of ActiveAdmin but this was my solution.